# Can I safely load previous save files?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I would like to revisit and re-do certain one-off events in this game such as Eventide Island. There's probably a save file where I haven't done Eventide yet - what will happen if I load that? Will the game keep my newest save files intact, so that I can resume normal play after a short time travel?

I assume it does, would be pretty awful if it somehow automatically overwrote manual saves - but I wanna check to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allowed one manual save and five auto-saves. The auto-saves happen rather frequently, by time interval, progression, and travel.

If you still have a save before Eventide, it would have to be the manual. If you loaded that the auto-saves would likely wipe out your current progress before you'd complete the island.

Save files on the Switch are tied to each console and cannot be transferred, however it might be possible to back up and restore saves on the Micro SD card by using a computer. I wouldn't want to be the one to test this theory out though.

Comment: hmm seems the only sensible solution is to start a new game on a separate account then. Didn't know that you can only have one manual save. Thanks!