# If I revert to an older save, are the later saves still there?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Here's the scenario. I got the Hylian shield (I'm sure I saved), I then got out of castle and travelled to buy ancient armor. Then bowling. Then re-up my arrows. I then saved again and ended my game. Today I started the game (after software update) and have the arrows, money, and armor, but the Hylian shield is nowhere to be seen.

I'm pretty sure I didn't drop it or anything else like that, but I guess it's possible. So my question is, if I go to my oldest autosave and it's still missing, am I able to go back to a more recent save? I don't want to lose more stuff.

If anyone else can suggest what my options are, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I don't know about the answer to your question, but you can get the Hylian Shield remade in Tarrey Town.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was holding off on that's as a last resort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed in [another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/303802/179563) there is one Manual Save and five Auto Saves. Your Manual Save will be overwritten only when you save the game yourself. The Auto Saves are made based on time and event triggers such as travelling to a shrine.

So, for your case I would suggest loading that oldest Auto Save to see if it has the Hylian Shield, then decide what you want to sacrifice before continuing from there. That much would be safe.

As @Cody mentioned in a comment you can repurchase the Hylian Shield, but it costs a pretty Rupee. 3,000, I think.

Comment: For whatever reason I didn't come access that link